# How to write on new string uses byte 'wb' mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working in 'wb' mode with array of bytes

```
for i in range(len(mas)):
    message.write(mas[i])
```

after I have to write data to a file on new line, for example '\n' in 'w' mode

```
for i in range(3):
    message.write(str(i))
    message.write("\n")

>>>0

>>>1

>>>2

>>>3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To write a string to a binary file you, like `"\n"` into `wb` mode, you must first [encode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) it by calling `string.encode('utf-8')` or any other encoding you need.

For example, to write a message to a binary file:

```
with open("a.txt", "wb") as f:
    line = str(0) + "\n\n"
    f.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

This would write `0\n\n`. To write the numbers from 0 to 3, followed by blank lines:

```
with open("a.txt", "wb") as f:
    for i in range(4):
        line = str(i) + "\n\n"
        f.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

Encoded newlines are printed as newlines correctly, so the following lines are equivalent:

```
open('a.txt', 'w').write('\n')
open('a.txt', 'wb').write('\n'.encode('utf-8'))
open('a.txt', 'wb').write(b'\n')
```

To print a literal `\n`, and not a newline, escape the backslash with another backslash `\\n` or write `r'\n'` to create a "raw" string.

Comment: I know this. I need to write data in the FILE on newline(in the file,not SHELL).

Comment: The lines above don't write anything to the shell. `f.write` writes to the `a.txt` file.

Comment: '\n' -transfer to new line in 'w' mode. I need to the same command in 'wb' mode.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to write a newline bytestring to your file after each of your bytearrays:

```
for i in range(len(mas)):
    message.write(mas[i])
    message.write(b"\n")
```

Note that a more natural (Pythonic) way of writing your loop is to iterate directly over `mas`, rather than iterating on a range and then indexing. You can also combine the two `write` calls into one:

```
for line in mas:
    message.write(line + b"\n")
```